# Proper way to clear a search input and the results?

Tags: reactjs

Imagine `input` has `value={this.state.searchText}`.

And `search()` calls the search query.

Which is the correct way to clear the input and the results? I assume you would need to re-run the query with `searchText: ''` after clearing the input to get the original results.

```
resetSearch = () => {
  this.setState({ searchText: '' }, () => {
    this.search();
  });
}

search = () => {
  searchQuery(this.state.searchText);
}
```

or

```
resetSearch = () => {
  this.setState({ searchText: '' });
  this.search('');
}

search = (query) => {
  searchQuery(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a stylistic choice.

In my opinion approach 1 is more explicit and easier to read - you know that search and searchQuery are clearly interacting with the state.

2nd approach is better for unit testing because it depends on the argument instead of component state.

In the end it's your call over readability/testability IMO.